# How to run a applet without making two separate file i.e .html and .java file in CMD. The html code is embedded into java code

Tags: java, html, cmd, compilation, applet

I want to run a applet file without making two separate file i.e .html and .java file in CMD. The html code is embedded into java code.

I tried running it using `appletviewer ColorDemo` as well as `appletviewer ColorDemo.html` when I create a different file for html file and run it, it works fine.

[This is the error I am getting while running the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQG9D.png)

This is the code I have been trying to run over cmd.

```
// Demonstrate color.
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
//html embedded in applet
/*
<applet code="ColorDemo" width=300 height=200>
</applet>
*/
public class ColorDemo extends Applet {
// draw lines

public void init()
{
    setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
Color c1 = new Color(255, 0, 0);
Color c2 = new Color(100, 255, 100);
Color c3 = new Color(100, 100, 255);
g.setColor(c1);
g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);

g.drawLine(0, 100, 100, 0);
g.setColor(c2);
g.drawLine(40, 25, 250, 180);
g.drawLine(75, 90, 400, 400);
g.setColor(c3);

}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Savin, glad to see you! Check that the file which your program is looking **does** exists. Because `it could not find the file specified`

Comment: yes @xameeramir it is showing as 'it could not find the file specified' but the .class file is present at the given location.

Comment: 1) Please learn how to copy text from the command line (DOS) It is more useful to both search engines and us.  2) `appletviewer ColorDemo.html` should be **`appletviewer ColorDemo.java`** in order to launch an applet the way you require.   That is how the [example on the applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) would work (see the comments just before the class declaration).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a *java zen*. However based on the error you're referring to:

- Check that the file which your program is looking **does** exists. Because `it could not find the file specified`
- Check whether it is [some privilege issue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc754344.aspx)

Comment: no Zameer @xameeramir, that isnt the main error if your read the whole error string you will find IO exception. The class file is already present in the specified dir.

Comment: Hmmm, I have seen many [IO exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9667170/2404470) because of security. Maybe the assumptions in this answer are wrong.